# Does coalesce(1) bring all the data to the driver?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The difference between `coalesce` and `repartition` is fairly straightforward. If I were to coalesce a DataFrame to 1 partition and write it to a storage service (Azure Blob/ AWS S3 etc), would the entire DataFrame be sent to the driver and then to the storage service; or would an executor send it directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spark official documentation describes it as follows:

> If you’re doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this
> may result in your computation **taking place on fewer nodes** than
> you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1).

From the above it can be inferred that it **should be an executor send it directly**.

Comment: I was thinking if we could verify this by adding the IP of the host as a literal column and saving the DataFrame...

Comment: You can verify whether the `df.write` method is running on a node in the cluster through the spark UI `executors` page.